# Does English have digraph GN that does not come from Norman (Old French)?

Tags: etymology, vocabulary

I noticed that in English the digraph GN appears in a strange way. Some examples I can find are the word stems *-cogn-, -sign-, -lign-*, all of which looks *very* similar to French counterparts. By this I think GN is of French origin, and should be borrowed into English as a result of the Norman conquest.

OTOH, in many words, GN is either pronounced separately or is at the beginning, which contradicts with the "French origin" hypothesis, because in French GN is pronounced like "ny" (e.g. ca**ny**on). And also note that this pronunciation is similar to other Germanic languages like German, but I can't find any similarity between a German word containing GN and an English -GN- word.

Words imported from Latin or Greek families via Old French *after* the Norman Conquest (1066 AD) might as well not be considered "native English", while I think [Romance-originated words borrowed into Old English before that](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/290547) are probably fair game (but there probably aren't any with "gn").

Comment: Define "natively". The vast majority of "English" words in use today were originally imported from other languages.

Comment: *Agnostic* is from Greek - it's an *a-* prefix but you don't explicitly rule that out. *Pugnacious* is apparently directly from Latin

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not an expert in that subject, but I wouldn't consider "different" as a "native" word, but I would agree if one says "word" is native.

Comment: I'm tempted to make an argument in favour of words of Celtic origin but I don't honestly think you can define *native English*

Comment: @ChrisH I tend to believe the mixed state of the contemporary English is because of French-speaking Normans conquered England, which caused a heavy mixture of French (Romance) and English (Germanic), and therefore I think anything before that is "more native". And there's another problem: I know zero Greek and its relationship with English.

Comment: That sounds like you should accept some words directly from Latin but by no means all, and most of Norse origin.

Comment: No idea if it's ye olde english, but 'reign' ?

Comment: @djsmiley2k "Reign" is from Old French around 13c. See https://www.etymonline.com/word/reign

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### At the start of words like *gnaw*

Yes, at the start of some words like *gnaw.* Even though the G in *gnaw* is “silent” in present-day English, it used to represent a consonant sound. So originally, the "GN" in this word wouldn't have been a "digraph" so much as a consonant cluster (albeit a special kind of consonant cluster: the sounds are "tautosyllabic" or in the same syllable). As the spelling suggests, the consonant cluster is thought to have originally been pronounced as [gn], although it may have developed other realizations in certain time periods.

The distinction in pronunciation between words starting with *gn-* and words starting with *n-* seems to have been lost sometime in the early Modern English time period (*[An Introduction to Early Modern English](https://books.google.com/books?id=2JQDrhvppv0C&pg=PA128&lpg=PA128),* by Terttu Nevalainen (2006), says the change of *gn-* to /n/ was "completed in the south in the eighteenth century", p. 128).

### In the middle of some compound words like *hangnail*

There are also some compound words made from native elements that are spelled with *-gn-,* such as *hangnail.*

### "G" itself isn't very frequent in non-word-initial position in native English vocabulary because of sound changes

The /g/ sound is a bit rare outside of word-initial position in native English vocabulary because it was historically vocalized in many contexts to /j/ or /w/.

The vocalization of G to /j/ (in palatalizing contexts) had already occurred by the time of Old English (at least, in West Saxon dialects), so the letter "G" in Old English spellings could represent the palatal glide /j/ (we have evidence for this from spellings that use G unetymologically to represent /j/ that did not originate from the Proto-Germanic *g sound; e.g. the word for *year,* cognate to German *Jahr,* was spelled with the letter G in old English). The Old English word *regn* that Laurel's answer mentions was probably pronounced something like /rejn/.

The vocalization of G to /w/, which occurred later, seems to have developed via rounding of earlier /ɣ/. An example is the Modern English word *owner* which the OED says had spellings like *agenere, agnere,* and *ahnere* in Old English. The Bosworth-Toller entry is at *[ágnere](http://www.bosworthtoller.com/038292).*

### The pronunciation of "-gn-" as /gn/ is not inconsistent with Latin, or even French origins for a word

The pronunciation of -gn- as /gn/ in many Latinate words is based on spelling (and also partly on certain traditions for pronouncing Latin, which may have themselves have been based on spelling): it doesn't have much if anything to do with Germanic. Note that even though *-gn-* is pronounced as /ɲ/ most of the time in French words, there are actually some learned French words where /gn/ is used, such as *ignition* and *stagnation.*

Comment: I don't like "hangnail" because it's more a compound of two words that happens to have GN in between. The gnaw one seems valid.

Comment: @iBug: In that case your question should not have asked about "letter sequence" but about them as a unit.

Comment: @R.. My bad because I initially meant "doublet" (I don't know if this word exists, but I know there's "triplet") **Edit**: OK I found that word. It's *bigram*.

Comment: @iBug What you are talking about is a [digraph](https://www.theschoolrun.com/What-is-a-digraph) (which most of us in the UK used to call a letter blend before educationalists got over-pedantic). A digraph is defined as a combination of two letters which represent one sound (th, ch, ph, st, sk and so on). 'Hangnail' includes **ng** as as a digraph but not **gn** since the second 'n' is pronounced normally and separately from the **ng** digraph.

Answer (score 12):

Old English had a lot of words spelled with "gn" somewhere in the word. With some patience you can get a pretty complete list on [Bosworth Toller's Anglo-Saxon Dictionary online](https://bosworthtoller.com/search/advanced) by doing a regular expression search for `gn` (the first 500ish hits are valid, the rest match words found in the body of the definition).

Cross checking with the OED, I see that very few current words have an etymology of "germanic" and are spelled still with a "gn" (most of them I've never heard of and were added to the language from German itself much later). The two I have heard of are ["gnat"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/gnat#etymonline_v_8993) and ["gnaw"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/gnaw), which both date back to Old English. One I haven't heard of is "agnail" (OE *angnægl,*), which according to the OED is etymologically from "the Germanic base of *ange* + the Germanic base of *nail*" (see also [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/hangnail#etymonline_v_1442)).

I do see there are plenty of words that are still used that lost the "gn". For example, "again" was once spelled *ongeagn*. In addition, "rain" was spelled *regn*.

Comment: gnarl, gnash, gnat, gnaw are all OE. ['gnu' is from dutch from german from khoisan 18th c.](https://www.etymonline.com/word/gnu).  ['gneiss' is from German 18th c.](https://www.etymonline.com/word/gneiss). [gnome' from French 18th c](https://www.etymonline.com/word/gnome#etymonline_v_8997)

Comment: 'Germanic' used 'g' to lengthen a preceding vowel (and 'gg' for actual non-initial /g/), resulting in 'wrong' pronunciations of many later Latin imports.

Comment: @Mitch According to https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gnarl, "gnarl" is a 19th century back formation probably from "knurl".

Answer (score 2):

Other words of English etymology using "gn" are gnarl, gnash, and gnat. As sumelic has pointed out, they are found at the beginning of these words.

Comment: Certainly "gnarl" seems to count as "native English", since it was invented in the 19th century! But "gnash" is probably Scandinavian (from old Norse). "gnat" is old English, or Germanic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing spelling and pronunciation.  English has tended to a certain (in some ways confusing) deviation in how different forms of the same root word is pronounced.  So:-

> In French we have the verb *prononcer* and the noun *prononciation*
>   In English we have the verb *pronounce* but the noun *pronunciation*

The French pronounce and spell the syllable in question verb and noun in exactly the corresponding way:  the English do not.

So with your word *sign*, The French pronounce the ‘g’ in ‘signe’ (strictly the ‘g’ and ‘n’ are slurred together as more like ‘ng’) in the same way as in the verb ‘signer’ and the noun ‘signal’ (Latin ‘signum’, probably, it is now thought, pronounced rather like today’s French).

But English, in adopting the word ‘signe’ has shifted its vowel sound from the ‘ee’ to the pronunciation of *sign* (as in line).  Yet in the noun *signal* this has not happened:  the ‘g’ is no longer silent, any more than it is in ‘signify’ (cp.  French ‘signifier’, pronounced like ‘signe’).  This kind of silent ‘g’ only occurs (as far as I can find) when it occurs in a final syllable (as in ‘resign’ - but ‘resignation’.

Another interesting example is French ‘ligne’, with English ‘line’ (not ‘lign’!).  Here the corresponding Latin is not ‘lignum‘ (which means ‘wood’!) but ‘linea’ (meaning ‘thread, or ‘line’, with no ‘g’, silent or otherwise).  I do not know why it is not spelled ‘line’ (pronounced ‘feen’) as in ‘fine’ (similarly pronounced).  After all, the noun ‘linéarité’ and adjective ‘linéaire’.

Where does that leave us?  First, it is an illustration of how language, including how it is pronounced and spelled, over time.  A major factor in this, above all in times when literacy was not as widespread and communication was more localised than it came to be by the end of the 18th century, was ‘natural selection’ and, as part of that, what how words sat comfortably in the mouth.  One key part of this was the so-called ‘great vowel shift’, in which letters ‘i’ and ‘e’ came to sit higher in the mouth.  So, we might think, as ‘ee’ shifted, the ‘g’ before ‘n’ became awkward to say and fell silent.  Meanwhile spelling partly sticks with old spelling and partly reacts to the most prevalent changes.

One other point is that it is difficult to speak of a ‘native’ version of ‘English’, or indeed of aboriginal English people.  ‘English’ is derived from the language of the germanic tribe of Angles, who invaded, as did the Saxons and then the Vikings, each with their own germanic dialects.  Before that had come the Romans, bringing with them people from all over western Europe, the middle East and North Africa.  Later, of course, came the French-speaking Normans, whose language filled the aristocracy and, no doubt the legal, medical and merchant professions, as well as Latin-using clerics, while much of the peasantry remained illiterate and had the most passing knowledge of French or Latin.  English as we know it emerged from the clash between the two languages.  So we see that the words for the most basic things are generally ‘anglo-saxon’ - ‘house’, ‘window’, ‘hand’, ‘where’, ‘go’, ‘foot’, ‘boat’, ‘day’, ‘night’...   The French involves things peasants would not possess or need.  As the two came together, the Anglo-Saxon tended to prevail  for most everyday purposes, while Franco-Latin and, indeed, Greek prevailed for professional, intellectual, technical legal and similar areas of life, of which the large mass of people had little contact.  There is no discoverable ‘native’ language.  It happened over hundreds of years.

So there is no native English in the sense you mean.  The language is a mongrel.

Comment: The general consensus view of linguists is that English is a Germanic language, so “native” English vocabulary is Germanic. It’s not that hard to identify. There are some people who argue for different analyses, like calling English a “creole”, but those are minority viewpoints. The presence of many loanwords in a language doesn’t make the concept of “native” vocabulary meaningless from the perspective of historical linguistics, even if it may make it harder for linguistically naive native speakers to identify originally native vs. originally borrowed words.

Comment: Japanese is an example of another language that has many loanwords, including old and well-integrated loans from Chinese, but that also has a stratum of native vocabulary (inherited from Proto-Japonic) that linguists can identify and analyze.

Comment: Well, yes, you are right:  I disagree with the consensus, and the questioner should be aware of that.  I should have mentioned it.  But there is far too much Franco-Latin in English to call as a whole germanic.  The French/Latin words (other than ‘pompom’ or legal jargon like ‘alias’ or ‘alibi’) are not loan words in any sense I can recognise.  They are as fully part of the language as the Angle, Saxon, Frisian and the rest.  I am not sure what purpose is served by looking for the earliest, when the two so clearly crashed together.

Comment: I was in the impression that "original" Germanic split into two groups/flavors, and the High German evolved into today's German, while Low German became English (and Dutch?), but I knew no further details and I thought it could be even earlier than Anglo-Saxon.

Comment: @iBug I don’t disagree.  I was not trying to explain the development of English in detail.  Essentially it is a combination of germanic and French.  It does not seem helpful to look for the truly native indigenous language:  both the English (well, British) and their language are essentially cross-breeds.

Comment: In French, *signe* and *ligne* rhyme. That's why they're spelled the same. This pronunciation evolved from two different pronunciations in Latin (the way that *write* and *right* are two words that are now pronounced the same, but in Old English were pronounced quite differently). French spelling is a little closer to pronunciation than English spelling is.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes.  Though what puzzles me is that, of course, one relevant French word, ‘ligne’ is not derived from Latin ‘lignum’, meaning ‘wood’!  The Latin for ‘line’ is ‘linea’.  And English is ‘line’, not ‘lign’, even though 11thC French had the masculine ‘lign’.  But this is a topic for another site:  the French one?

Comment: @TuffyL I don't know very much about historical French sound changes, but I think *linea* could easily have turned into *leenya,* which is essentially the way the French pronounced *ligne* before they stopped pronouncing mute e's.  Similarly, *vigne* came from Latin *vinea*. *Signum* turned into *seenya* via a different set of sound changes.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes:  I was about to write back suggesting it must have something to do with phonics.  Thank you for these interesting point.  I  upvoted your previous reply and close before this falls foul of the ‘chat’ rule.  OUT!